# how to intercept LUIS intent responce on a different server

Tags: azure-language-understanding

I have a mobile native app using Bing Speech & LUIS services. After the intent "text" is received I call my business app API with the intent text.

Basically 2 server calls - one to get the intent the other to my API with the intent.

So, is it possible to call Bing + LUIS and have an event handler on my Azure App Server to receive the intent i.e. without going back to mobile interface and invoking the API call from mobile.

regards

-Ravi

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you cannot just route through the server? e.g. the chatbot sends the user's text to the server, and the server calls LUIS, receives and handles the response, then formulate a response to send to the chatbot.

Comment: We considered that Steven. The cognitive platform offerings for STT/TTS/LUIS etc. built for (a) live streaming of voice (b) Scale & Availability. So, if we move that to our app server, we have to account for voice decoder and infra and middleware for routing the stream to cognitive services. In addition cognitive services like CRIS expect live streaming for STT and not via a relayed route. Will share our learnings. regards.